# Twisted Python - access SMTPFactory attribute from Application

Tags: python, attributes, smtp, protocols, twisted

For once, a simple, straightforward question from me! Can someone please suggest how I can access "p.startedTLS" in the ConsoleSmtpFactory code below, from within the ConsoleMessage class?

I want to be able to dump to file, as part of the message, whether it was delivered over TLS...

So to put it another way - in Twisted, can your application code access protocol attributes? (I think that's what I'm trying to ask?!?

I've even tried using global variables (let's ignore coding standard issues for a minute!)... No joy. "buildProtocol" in my CustomSmtpFactory below is called before p.StartedTLS gets set to true - which I guess is obvious in hindsight - it builds the factory, and startedTLS gets set in ext_STARTTLS (in ESMTP class) upon receipt of "STARTTLS" command from client.

So I guess my question more accurately is - how to access protocol attributes, AFTER the Protocol has been built?

Thanks!

```
class ConsoleMessageDelivery:
    implements(custom_esmtp.IMessageDelivery)

    def receivedHeader(self, helo, origin, recipients):
        by = helo[1]
        from_ = origin
        target = ""
        for u in recipients:
           target = target + u.__str__() + "\n"
        """ 
        Want to add something here like:
        tls=protcol.startTLS 
        then add "tls" to the returned string below
        """
        return "Client: %s\nFrom: %s\nTo: %s\n\n" % (by, from_, target)

    def validateFrom(self, helo, origin):
        return origin

    def validateTo(self, user):
        return lambda: ConsoleMessage()
        #return None


class ConsoleMessage:
    implements(custom_esmtp.IMessage)

    def __init__(self):
        self.lines = []

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        self.lines.append(line)

    def dumpMsgToFile(self, msgData):
        inx = 0
        filePrefix = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f")
        while os.path.exists(filePrefix + "-" + str(inx)):
           inx = inx + 1
        fileName = filePrefix + "-" + str(inx)
        msgFile = open("./" + fileName,"a")
        msgFile.writelines(msgData)
        msgFile.write ("\n----------------------\n")
        msgFile.close()

    def eomReceived(self):
        print "\n".join(self.lines)
        self.dumpMsgToFile(self.lines)
        self.lines = None
        return defer.succeed(None)

    def connectionLost(self):
        # There was an error, throw away the stored lines
        self.lines = None


class ConsoleSMTPFactory(custom_esmtp.SMTPFactory):
    protocol = custom_esmtp.mySMTP

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        custom_esmtp.SMTPFactory.__init__(self, *a, **kw)
        self.delivery = ConsoleMessageDelivery()

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        try:
           caCertFile = open("/opt/tesa/etc/certs/CA/cacert.pem","r")
           certFile = open("/opt/tesa/etc/certs/server/server.crt","r")
           keyFile = open("/opt/tesa/etc/certs/server/server.key","r")
           caCertData = caCertFile.read()
           pKeyData = keyFile.read()
           certData = certFile.read()
        except IOError as e:
           print "Failed in reading files({0}): {1}".format(e.strerrror)
        except:
           print "Unknown error"

        caCert = ssl.Certificate.loadPEM(caCertData)
        cert = load_certificate(FILETYPE_PEM, certData)
        pKey = load_privatekey(FILETYPE_PEM, pKeyData)
        sslCtxFactory = ssl.CertificateOptions(privateKey=pKey, certificate=cert, trustRoot=caCert)
        p = custom_esmtp.SMTPFactory.buildProtocol(self, addr)
        p.delivery = self.delivery
       # p.challengers = {"LOGIN": LOGINCredentials, "PLAIN": PLAINCredentials}
        p.ctx=sslCtxFactory
        print (p.startedTLS) # << returns true / false depending on if switched to TLS
        return p


class SimpleRealm:
    implements(IRealm)

    def requestAvatar(self, avatarId, mind, *interfaces):
        if smtp.IMessageDelivery in interfaces:
            return smtp.IMessageDelivery, ConsoleMessageDelivery(), lambda: None
        raise NotImplementedError()


def main():
    from twisted.application import internet
    from twisted.application import service

    portal = Portal(SimpleRealm())
    checker = InMemoryUsernamePasswordDatabaseDontUse()
    checker.addUser("guest", "password")
    portal.registerChecker(checker)

    a = service.Application("Console SMTP Server")
    internet.TCPServer(5000, ConsoleSMTPFactory(portal)).setServiceParent(a)

    return a

application = main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a feature that's missing from the SMTP implementation.  I think that `origin` is an IP address as a string.  It probably should have been a more fully-featured address object, representing not only the peer address of the client but also the transport in use to communicate with the client.

Or perhaps it's an even more general failing in the way the SMTP protocol implementation interacts with the portal (or delivery object or delivery factory object).  Maybe it should be exposing more information to begin with (as opposed to a solution where it holds this back until, say,  `receivedHeader` is called).

Anyhow, the basic answer is that this is an unsupported feature (it would make a good feature request in the Twisted issue tracker).  You might find a way to hack up the functionality you want by overriding `receivedHeader` on your `ESMTP` subclass (read the base implementation) to supply the necessary extra information to the delivery object.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-PaulCalderone - Shame it's a missing feature, but I guess I can take a bit of pride that for the first time since I've been posting twisted questions, I asked a fairly decent one ;) When I'm back in work on Monday I'll look to add the request, and hack around ESMTP :) Thanks again :)

Comment: Actually @Jean-PaulCalderone - if we wanted to get the full SMTP header from the received message - I'm guessing this would be the same feature request effectively? Or can this already be done with my existing code (in a way I have missed) ?? Thanks! ((Not trying to ask a different question here in a comment - just trying to "refine" answer!)

Comment: (twisted ticket #7695 raised)